# The "plague" and its transmission by "fleas", or "flies"

Tags: etymology

"[fly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fly)", Ger "Fliege" (the insect drosophila) could theoretically reflect an earlier *plag. It is linked with "to fly" though, to nobody's surprise.

> Old English flȳġe, flēoge (“a fly”), from Proto-Germanic *fleugǭ (“a fly”), from Proto-Indo-European *plewk- (“to fly”)

But maybe there is more to it. How does it compare to *flea* and eitherway to *plague*?

*plague* is a biblical symbolism, isn't it?

Comment: I'm sorry this is such a low effort question. It was still autosaved in the text box and I wanted to get it out of there. I don't remember my reasoning anymore and don't have the search history backed up either. It was plagued by uncertainties in various etymologies.

Answer (score 0):

"Plague" comes from Latin *plāga* "wound" from *plangō* "to strike", via French. Wiktionary claims it's cognate to Dutch *vloeken* "to clash with".

The only Latin cognate I can find for PIE **pl-w-* "to fly, flow, move swiftly" is *pluit*, "to rain". The meaning "to fly" seems mostly restricted to Germanic and Balto-Slavic.

Comment: Cp: G *Fluch* "curse", same root, surely influenced by Lithurgy; *Flucht* "flight, a fleeing", long and short vowels respectively, similar to *Suche* "search" / *Sucht* "addiction" (in principle one of the temptations, or *sins*; punished with *plagues*; akin to E *sick*); also cp *Ruch* (???) *verrucht* "infamous"; syn. *einschlägig* <? *schlagen* "punch, beat"), *Rache* "revenge", *Rache-Gelüste* "rage? desire for revenge", for the ablaut, further *eek*, G *igit, Ekel*. Thus perhaps compare *rat*, and *s-* (I'm not gonna guess), *Egel* "eel" for vermin. Cp *shoot* for semantic development.

Comment: *blood rain* was one of the plagues (meteor strike? cp Ger *Ader* "blood vessel; pocket of ore", PIE \*HesHr "blood" vs G *Eisen*, /z/, "iron", *Eis* "ice", voiceless /s/ in analogy to *Wasser*? *blood* vs Turk *bulut* "cloud"--vapour, essence? cp *blow [wind]* ~ *blow [strike] ~ beat [of the heart]*?). How many strikes does one have on SE, seven?

Comment: cp further *bulge*, G *Beule*, *Buckel*, Fr *boule* probably \*bhew- (bow) or \*bhl-w- but the velars are unexplained, see *Beulenpest* (that skin infection). Also cp G *flachliegen* "to be sick; lie flat"; *rash* (Ger *Aus-Schlag*); G *Flechte* (kind of rash, also moss etc.; cp *flechten* "to wicker[work?]", err, [*ap-pl-ique*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510743/stitched-applications/510761?r=SearchResults#510761); *plunge* vs figuratively *plummeting [health]*; *flight [of stairs], Ger *Flucht* (slews in architecture? e.g. corners of a room, that extended lines *run* to) ...

Comment: cp: *cough* ~ G *Husten* vs a) *clog*, cf Ger 1. *stopfen* "jam, pack, stuff", *verstopfen* "to clog", also *stopper* ~ *stöpsel*, *Stau* "jam" vs 2. *stopfen*, *flicken* "to plug [clothes' holes]" (viz *applique*, *flechten* again), *stricken* "to weave, needle work", *constrict*, *sticken* "stitch", *stecken* "to stick", *ersticken* "suffocate"; cp *suffer* to *sick* above (cp *laugh* /f/), thus *suck*; cp G *sickern* "sink in", G *Suff[kopf]* "drunken idiot" but ~ *Suff, saufen, Saft* < \*seH-p, cp. *Saft* "blood, humours, vigor, juice", *saugen* "suck", *Blut-Sauger*; b) onom. *hiks*

Comment: @vectory I have no idea what you're trying to say in those comments; they read like free association with no structure. What does the number of strike ones has on SE, or the Turkish word for "cloud", have to do with this question or answer?